# In Expo (React Native), I'm getting error during 'Run fastlane': DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled

Tags: react-native, expo

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Creating Gymfile
Gymfile created
Successfully loaded '/Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Gymfile' 

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                           Detected Values from './Gymfile'                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| suppress_xcode_output     | true                                                     |
| clean                     | false                                                    |
| scheme                    | MYPROJECTNAME                                            |
| configuration             | Release                                                  |
| export_options            |                                                          |
| export_xcargs             | OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain /var/folders/tp/...    |
| disable_xcpretty          | true                                                     |
| buildlog_path             | /Users/expo/workingdir/logs                              |
| output_directory          | ./build                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Resolving Swift Package Manager dependencies...

$ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./MYPROJECTNAME.xcworkspace -scheme MYPROJECTNAME -configuration Release

▸ 2023-09-07 08:23:03.145 xcodebuild[7031:16561] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
▸ Command line invocation:
▸     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./MYPROJECTNAME.xcworkspace -scheme MYPROJECTNAME -configuration Release
▸ User defaults from command line:
▸     IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
▸ resolved source packages:

$ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ./MYPROJECTNAME.xcworkspace -scheme MYPROJECTNAME -configuration Release
[stderr] 2023-09-07 08:23:04.997 xcodebuild[7037:16677] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
Command timed out after 3 seconds on try 1 of 4, trying again with a 6 second timeout...
[stderr] 2023-09-07 08:23:07.921 xcodebuild[7037:16690] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.InterfaceBuilderBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition
[stderr] 2023-09-07 08:23:08.174 xcodebuild[7046:16713] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
[stderr] 2023-09-07 08:23:08.645 xcodebuild[7046:16745] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.InterfaceBuilderBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition

Detected provisioning profile mapping: {:"dk.example.MYPROJECTNAME-api"=>"bbbaf28e-0fd9-4093-a412-15c3a8ce99a1"}

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                 Summary for gym 2.213.0                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The `Run fastlane` actually continues after this error. The very last line(s) are these:

```
Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project

It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
sure your project is set up correctly.
fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there

[stderr]    [!] Error building the application - see the log above
Error: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. 
Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
```

This error happened after:

- I [upgraded from Expo version 48, to Expo version 49](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-49-c6d398cdf740).
- I updated my `npm`-version from version 16.x to 18.x (and set that as default in `nvm`).
- During that Expo-upgrade, I also [added Sentry](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/#install-and-configure-sentry). I did remove it again, because of this bug.

**Overarching question:**

How do I get past this error, when I run the `eas build`-command?

And can I run the `run fastlane`-step locally, so I don't need to pay 2 USD, for every solution attempt? Grr!

---

### Solution attempt 1: Run `pod install`

I found this [React Native issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/38263) that had the same bug, where someone suggested running `pod install`. I tried that, and got the same error.

### Solution attempt 2: Debug failed `Run fastlane`

I found a bunch of solutions in here: [eas build -p ios | Fastlane build failed with unknown error](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1079). I tried playing around with the [prebuild](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/), but React Native is quite new to me, so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing.

None of this worked. Same error, all the way through.

I also tried putting this:

```
{
  "build": {
    ...
    "production-ios": {
      "ios": {
        "image": "latest"
      },
      "distribution": "store",
      "releaseChannel": "production.ios-1.7.1"
    }
  }
}
```

into my `eas.json` and ran the build with that profile: `eas build -p ios --profile production-ios`.

### Solution attempt 3: Restart computer and (re-?)installed `eas`

After the restart, I weirdly enough, couldn't get `eas` to work. When I ran: `which eas` it said: `eas not found`. I'm wondering if this is related to it? And maybe `eas` was installed in the global version 16.x of my `npm`-setup? Hmm...

I then ran: `npm install -g eas-cli` and then ran a new build.

---

I have previously tried upgrading Expo to version 49, but that was immediately after the new version came out. I never got it work back end either. [My attempts were logged here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76653474/how-to-debug-react-native-expo-app-crashing-on-ios-after-updating-expo-sdk-to-v).

Comment: I started getting this error a few days ago with no code changes to my app. (It last built successfully on EAS 19 days ago). So something changed.

Answer (score 2):

I had commited my `ios`-folder, which meant that it skipped the `prebuild`-step in the build process. And I think something was faulty about the Sentry-setup I had done, which made it fail.

By deleting my `ios` folder completely and commit the deletion of those files, made `eas build` succeed.

These two documentation pages led me to this:

- [Expo Prebuild](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/)
- [Expo iOS build](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/ios-builds/)

---

There was another solution attempt here, that I never tried: [Add bitcode to false in app.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74434035/expo-sdk-46-ios-build-failed-in-fastlane-step?rq=2).